# Why does my USB disk show as having no files, but hundreds of gigabytes used?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

Today, I installed Windows 10 Enterprise on my computer. I have a USB disk, but I met this problem:

> Local Disk (G:): 117 GB free of 465 GB
>
> This PC > Local Disk (G:): This folder is empty.

[image]

[image]

How to resolve that problem? I never met this trouble before, please tell what s wrong in here?

Comment: What's wrong with these screenshots? Did you have some files on that disk?

Comment: @gronostaj First screenshot says "117 GB free of 465 GB", second screenshot says "This folder is empty." for the root folder.

Comment: @sukihinata, I edited your question somewhat to try to highlight what your problem is. I don't think this changed your intent in any way, but if you feel it did, by all means feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: Run `attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*` in a `cmd` shell.

Comment: I really have very lot important file in that disk. I don't know what happen going on?

Comment: C:\Users\fruit>attrib -h -r -s /s /d g:\*.*
File not found - G:\*.*

Comment: Did I post this clear?

Comment: just go to cmd prompt go into drive g: and from there
type attrib -h -r -s /s /d

Comment: I do like you say, arana. I upload image in my question that problem .Can you help me a little more?

Comment: Are you able to search any of the contents saved in the disk before? If yes, Files may be hidden or some virus issue. Or you may also try other OS or using a live Linux to check if the contents are there.

Comment: @sukihinata Was this disk taken out of the computer and put in another computer or just taken out and put back in? I have an idea of what your problem is but I just want to make sure my assumptions are correct before I post an answer.

Comment: This is a long shot, but worth a try. You could go to 'my computer', go to the properties of drive g:. On the tab security you can see if your user account is mentioned and check if your users has "full control" of the disk. If not, try to add your user account or apply 'full control'.

Comment: Another option is to go to computer management (start-> type "computer management") and than to drive management. There you should check if maybe there is another drive using g:. If so, change the driveletter to an unused one.

Comment: I one time have see my friend use essgos guru software to fix usb problem. can i use software to fix hard drive?

Comment: Is this an hard drive that you removed from inside the computer and placed in a custom external USB enclosure? If yes, what brand/model enclosure? In addition, your screen shots show a preview build.

Answer (score 0):

What you may have is a GPT Protected Partition. Check this by Right Clicking on Computer and going to Manage. Go to Disk Management and see if your drive shows something like this.

[image: GPT Partition]

In a nutshell your files and everything are still on there but can't be read because it is used in a different EFI location in its hardware record.

GPT was used to get around MBR issues. I have had this issue before. In most cases it is because you moved one drive from one machine to another OR you moved your drive from one SATA port to another SATA port. It can be a pain because in most cases you would just have to rebuild the MBR but GPT makes it a little messier.

More Information here: [Troubleshooting GPT Protective Partitions](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/207837en?language=en_US)

If the drive your having issue with is in the same computer just put it back in the same SATA port it was originally in. If it was put into a different computer I am unsure what you can do about the partition. You can use this link as there are a number of options you can try.

[Restoring Data From GPT](https://www.google.com/search?q=gpt%20protective%20partition&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=&safe=active)

Hope this helps at all.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention those solutions. From what I can see in various links, wikii, and Microsoft, GPT *should be* mountable and readable (but not bootable) when migrated to another computer. Your Seagate link mentions a "solution" of repartitioning but in the context of win xp 32 bit. The OP mentions USB, perhaps this is an enclosure/firmware issue.(?)

Comment: @Yorik very true. There are a lot of suggestions and most of them are clear the partition and make a new one if it is a GPT. I, like you, are waiting to see more information about the Hard Drive and the setup. I figured I would make this answer maybe to lead him to look into the option.

Comment: Hello everyone. I got fixed my problem. Thanks you everyone!! :)

Comment: @sukihinata What was the answer?

Comment: I just restart  my computer.